# make sure the MySQL server starts at boot

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, hive

hi guys I have download chkconfig from the website,but when I want to run it this error shows up

```
sudo: chkconfig: command not found
```

I have put the chkconfig file inside this path:

/usr/local

I’m using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

All what I want to do is to check on MySQL if running or on, using this command:

```
sudo chkconfig mysql on
```

Comment: Wrong site but chkconfig is a red hat thing.   Try service or updates-rc.d

Comment: so after i get it where is the best path to put it in?,and how i run the command with is it gonna be updates-rc.d mysql on ?

Comment: check this out sudo: sysv-rc: command not found